# AWS java SDK does not honor log4j properties

Tags: log4j, aws-java-sdk

Whenever I use AWS Java SDK I get bombarded with crazy amount of logs because it being set to debug and I cannot get it to stay quite.

Below is the result of the output with `-Dlog4j.debug` flag.

it shows that my log4j.properties file has been read and parsed.  With root logger at `OFF` and `com.amazonaws` at `WARN` but I'm still seeing debug level logging.  Am I missing something?

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/p-test/target/scala-2.11/phoenix-test-assembly-81fc4750d1.jar!/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/p-test/target/scala-2.11/phoenix-test-assembly-81fc4750d1.jar!/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[OFF].
log4j: Level token is [OFF].
log4j: Category root set to OFF
log4j: Parsing for [com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.http.wire] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category org.apache.http.wire set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.http.wire=[null]
log4j: Parsing for [com.amazonaws] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category com.amazonaws set to WARN
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.amazonaws=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
17:30:39.808 [main] INFO  c.g.e.p.PhoenixTestApplication$ - ### Starting Phoenix write test
17:30:39.814 [main] INFO  c.g.e.p.PhoenixTestApplication$ - numThreads: x10
17:30:39.815 [main] INFO  c.g.e.p.PhoenixTestApplication$ - maxThreads: x10
17:30:39.815 [main] INFO  c.g.e.p.PhoenixTestApplication$ - ### initializing ###
17:30:39.884 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient - Internal logging successfully configured to commons logger: true
17:30:39.953 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics - Admin mbean registered under com.amazonaws.management:type=AwsSdkMetrics
17:30:40.103 [main] DEBUG c.a.internal.config.InternalConfig -     Configuration override awssdk_config_override.json not found.
18:01:51.313 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-171] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.AmazonS3Client - Bucket region cache doesn't have an entry for bucket. Trying to get bucket region from Amazon S3.
18:01:51.313 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-239] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.AmazonS3Client - Bucket region cache doesn't have an entry for bucket. Trying to get bucket region from Amazon S3.
18:01:51.313 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-219] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.AmazonS3Client - Bucket region cache doesn't have an entry for bucket. Trying to get bucket region from Amazon S3.
18:01:51.313 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-47] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.AmazonS3Client - Bucket region cache doesn't have an entry for bucket. Trying to get bucket region from Amazon S3.
18:01:51.313 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-73] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.AmazonS3Client - Bucket region cache doesn't have an entry for bucket. Trying to get bucket region from Amazon S3.
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS SDKs uses logback rather than log4j, so you have to define logback.xml configuration file in resource folder